# Migrating from MySQL to SQL Server, How to Implement Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have this trigger that I wrote for a MySQL environment, and which I now need to transfer to a SQL Server environment.

Being unfamiliar with Transact SQL, I have a little trouble translating from one to the other or creating an equivalent. Here is the simplified query:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER <myTrigger> BEFORE INSERT ON <myTable>

IF NEW.<myColumnContainingBoolean> = TRUE THEN
    SET NEW.<myColumnReferenceCode> = CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW()), 'indice');
ENDIF;
```

The goal is to add a reference number (today's date writted yyyymmdd + 'indice') according to the value of a boolean contained in the query, to summarize, if, at the time of the INSERT, the value of the boolean is on TRUE then we insert the code on this same line, otherwise we don't write a reference. Here is a maybe more explicit example :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu7mp.png)

I have sincerely tried a lot of things, what seems to come closest to my request is this one (which, of course, does not work):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER <myTrigger>
ON <myTable>
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    IF <myColumnContainingBoolean> 
        SET <myColumnReferenceCode> = CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),DAY(GETDATE()), 'indice');
    FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Comment: A simple `FORMAT(getdate(),'yyyymmd')+'indice'` will generate the string you want. You can probably use this as a `DEFAULT` for the column, eg `DEFAULT (case theBoolean when 1 then FORMAT(getdate(),'yyyymmd')+'indice' else null end)`

Comment: This particular instance doesn't look like the best use of a trigger.  Have you considered using a calculated column or incorporating the logic into the process that initiates the insert?

Comment: You can use probably use `CASE` in a DEFAULT.

Comment: @bbaird : Thank, sadly I don't have control at this time on the process initiating the insert, and I didn't know the existence of calculated column, I'll look.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I've tried your solution, here is the error message : The name <column name containing the boolean> is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: In that case you'll have to join the target table with `inserted` and update it, eg `update targetTable set refCode=... from inserted inner join targetTable on TargetTable.ID=inserted.ID where inserted.BoolColumn=1`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't know you can use `case` in a `default` constraint, thanks!

Comment: @ZoharPeled You can, but it cannot reference other columns (at least in SQL Server)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When using format, `mm` is minutes, `MM` is month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess we have to use a trigger (**immense sigh**).

Here's how you would do it in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TRIGGER <your schema>.<your table>_Insert ON <your schema>.<your table>
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO <your schema>.<your table> (<your other columns>,<myColumnReferenceCode>) 
    SELECT
      <your other columns>
     ,CASE
        WHEN <myColumnContainingBoolean> = 1 THEN FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd') + 'indice'
        ELSE <myColumnReferenceCode>
      END 
    FROM
      inserted 
END
GO
```

If you're using an auto-incremented (`IDENTITY`) column, make sure to leave it off your insert list inside the trigger.

Other observations: You could probably just make `<myColumnReferenceCode>` a date and store `GETDATE()` and get the same functionality, but I don't know all of your circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to reproduce and implement the query without problem. It doesn't work though, because it seems that in my context the request (produced automatically by PowerApps) is an Update and not an Insert (sorry for the bad information, I don't have control over the PowerApps form and I have been misinformed), I get the following error message:

https://imgur.com/yf0Qw1V . It would seem that the only way to solve it is to modify the form itself, and unfortunately I still do not have the rights to do so.

Comment: **shakes fist in air**  Good luck on your adventure.